# Bootstrap - Align control-labels properly when labels span across 2 lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap control group and control label.

For each label/input I am wrapping it like so:

```
<div class="span5">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">
    <div class="controls">
      <input>
      <div !-- some hidden help block -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to fit two of these per row, so I have all of them set to span5 within a single row-fluid

However, some of my labels are quite long and won't fit into a single line within the span5 alotted. So the labels end up being split into multiple lines but only the first line is vertically in line with the input like so:

[image]

I would like it so that instead of the first line being vertically aligned, the entire label is vertically aligned (so if the label is 2 lines the gap between the 2 lines is vertically aligned with the input).

Is this possible to do using bootstrap?

Comment: Please share the code on JSFiddle

Comment: I'm not really familiar with bootstrap, as a lot of this is inserted by a framework. I'm trying to replicate this in jsfiddle but the control-label seems to display above the input rather than beside it. Do you know why this is? http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/1245/

Comment: do you need 2 blocks placed next to each other. or your problem is about the spacing in the text row space?? [Check this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKBWmV?editors=1111)

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you want to do. But below is the code I did to implement what I understood from the question.

```
<div class="container p-4">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="input2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">Monthly Vacation Carried Over (Days)</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" style="width: 50%;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="input3" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">Monthly Vacation Carried Over (Days)</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input3" style="width: 50%;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the styles for the small screen devices.

```
@media(max-width: 576px) {
                .form-control {
                    width: 100% !important;
                }
                label {
                    text-align: left;
                }
            }
```

> **SIDE NOTE:**
>
> I used Bootstrap V.4 (Beta). The latest.